# Async Include PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asynchronous, include

Maybe this is a noob question, anyway.
We all know the `include('foo.php')` function.
Actually I have a webpage made by several php includes.
Obviusly not all the content is above the fold, so no need to load everything immediately.
Is there a way to async include this files? There is no button to press, but I really would like something like lazyload does for images, or at least a async load like some jQuery scripts.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't lazy load PHP but you can lazy load images and js but you need js to do it. Also think carefull about using jQuery. It's a huge library of which you'll most likely only use a small part of. Also the way the question is now it's too broad. We are not here to write the code for you

Comment: jQuery(or pure Javascript)+AJAX

Comment: Simply I forget the possibility to use 'infinite scroll' :)
It was 5 years ago the last time I wrote a line of code :)